# Finite difference second order central in time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

Is it valid to approximate $u_t$ for a second order central finite difference?.

I mean $u_t=\frac{u_m^{n-1}-2u_m^{n}+u_m^{n+1}}{k^2}$, does it approximate the first partial differential derivate of $u$ with respecto of $t$?.

I have the next PDE system and I want to use finite difference, but is it correct to approximate the first partial difference of $u$ with respect of $t$ for a second order central difference scheme in time?. For what I've been stuying it will be correct if and only if $u_{tt}=\frac{u_m^{n-1}-2u_m^{n}+u_m^{n+1}}{k^2}$, I mean, the second derivate of $u$ with respect of $t$.

Comment: You want the approximation of the second time derivative to be an approximation to the first time derivative. This is not correct, of course. Correct approximation for $u_t$ is for example $u_t(x_m,t_n)=\frac{u_m^{n+1}-u_m^{n-1}}{2k}+O(t^2)$ where $k$ is the time step.

Comment: @Svetoslav that is want I wanted to know. So It is not correct to approximate $u_t$ for a second order central scheme right?

Comment: Yes, the formula on the second line of your post is not correct.

Comment: @Svetoslav so the correct question could be:

How to use a central difference scheme in time and space for the next PDE system:

$u_t=D_u u_{xx}-u+av+u^2v\\
v_t=D_v v_{xx}+b-av-u^2v\\$

Where $D_u,D_v,a,b$ are constants?

Comment: Also, you can use $u_t=\frac{u_m^{n+1}-u_m^n}{\tau}+O(\tau)$

Comment: @Svetoslav so for mi PDE's system, wich would be the very best way to use finite differences of second order centered in time and space?

Comment: I can not say. Better post a separate question.